# How to change org.apache.cxf.stax.maxTextLength using CXF.xml

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I encountered the following error:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unmarshalling Error: Text size
>   limit (134217728) exceeded

It's simply says that there's max text size limitation via SOAP web service.
According to the [Securing CXF Services](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/security.html) documentation, it's possible to define the following property in the CXF.xml file:

> org.apache.cxf.stax.maxTextLength

My question is how to do it? Where in the file should write it?

I'm new to Java, thank you for help

Comment: What version of cxf are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too late ... :)

For me, this worked on JBoss EAP 6.4 :

First, create a file nammed *webservice-conf.xml* into *WEB-INF/* :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxws-config xmlns="urn:jboss:jbossws-jaxws-config:4.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jbossws-jaxws-config:4.0 schema/jbossws-jaxws-config_4_0.xsd">
    <endpoint-config>
        <config-name>Sample</config-name>

        <property>
            <property-name>org.apache.cxf.stax.maxTextLength</property-name>
            <property-value>268435456</property-value>
        </property>


    </endpoint-config>
</jaxws-config>
```

You can specify the maximum size by setting the property value of *org.apache.cxf.stax.maxTextLength* , it's in bytes.

Then, on your web service implementation, add the *@EndpointConfig* annotation :

```
@WebService
@EndpointConfig(configName = "Sample", configFile = "WEB-INF/webservice-conf.xml") 
public class SampleService implements ISampleService {
}
```

Please note that *configName* value in the annotation must match with *config-name* in the XML file.

It's worked for me

Comment: Is it possible to make it work with environment variable?